# Testing a Controller using Jasmine in Karma

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a controller but I'm getting an error

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'apply' ReferenceError:
>   inject is not defined

The unit-test.js is

```
define(['angular',
        'myApp',
        'angularMocks',
        'MyCtrl'
], function() {

describe('Testing controller', function() {
        var $scope = null;
        var ctrl = null;

        beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        }));


     describe('MyCtrl', function () {
        it('should call test variable', function () {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();

                ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope
                });

                expect($scope.test).toBe("sth");
            });
        });

    });
});
```

in MyCtrl I have declared a `$scope.test = "sth";`

When I change

`beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));` to `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`

I'm getting `ReferenceError: module is not defined`

I use Karma version: 0.9.8 and AngularJS v1.0.8

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that you're using requirejs ? If yes i can post an aswer and say to you how implements the config of require.js for karma

Comment: Yes indeed, I use requirejs but I think both files (karma.conf.js and test-main.js) are correct.

Comment: I've post the answer with complete config and modifications on your test file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a lot of things to do if you're using requirejs.

First you have to put the `karma-requirejs` plugin in your `package.json`

```
"karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
```

Then you have ti change your config file. You have to add `requirejs` in `frameworks` part
Then exclude your require `main.js`

Then add all your librairies files via the `pattern` config and not `include` it

You have to add your require `main-test.js` (config file for test describe at bottom)

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({ 
        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

        files: [
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js', included: false},

            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/scripts/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'test/spec/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
            'test/main-test.js'
        ],

        exclude: ['app/scripts/main.js'],

        port: 8082,

        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Now create your `main-test.js`.

In you have to get all your tests files to put it as dependencies.

Then do a classic requirejs config (note in the `baseUrl` we use `/base` a karma constant)  and finally start karma by code through : `window.__karma__.start();`

Example :

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}

require.config({

    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '/base/app/scripts',

    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery.min',
        angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular.min',
        angularMocks: '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
        ngResource: '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min'
    },

    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        angular: {
            deps: [ 'jquery', 'bootstrap'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        ngResource: {
            deps: [ 'angular' ],
            exports: 'ngResource'
        },
        angularMocks: {
            deps: [ 'ngResource' ],
            exports: 'angularMocks'
        }
    },

    priority: [
        'angular'
    ],

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests

});

require(tests, function(){
    window.__karma__.start();
});
```

In your test file :

change `beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));` to `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`

Change the params of your define like that :

```
define(['angular',
        'myApp',
        'angularMocks',
        'MyCtrl'
], function(angular, myApp, angularMocks, MyCtrl)
```

To inject controller just do that (You have to put the `MyCtrl` in param of your require function) :

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller(MyCtrl, {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));
```

And finally :

```
it('should call crudListMethods', function () {
    expect(scope.test).toBe("sth");
});
```

Now it should work ! Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas but I'm still getting a ReferenceError: module is not defined

Comment: I added that and I also tried , function('angular', 'myApp', 'angularMocks', 'MyCtrl') { but unfortunately I'm still getting module is not defined. Thank you for your effort it's really appreciated.

Comment: Your karma config file and main-test file are the same than me ? Test it with my conf please

Comment: I had wrong angular-mocks file. I accepted your answer as a solution, merci bocu Thomas.